# Adding spinboxes to tab widget?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to dynamically add spinboxes but I need them to be on a different tab which I have created in the designer. Is it possible for me to add them to a tab instead of the main window?

`QSpinBox *spin[10];
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         spin[i] = new QSpinBox(this);
         spin[i]->setValue(i);
         spin[i]->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100),QSize(50,50))); //todo: change position
         spin[i]->show();
    }`

Comment: so are you using a `QTabWidget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the `QSpinBox`, use the tab as the parent.

In your example you are using `this`, which I'm going to assume is the widget you've designed in the designer.

As an example, if you had an empty widget in the designer and dragged a `QTabWidget` onto it, it will create a `QTabWidget` called `tabWidget`. By default it has two tabs (which are `QWidget`s) called `tab` and `tab_2`. Also, by default, the designer creates a member variable in your class called `ui` which represents your widget.

Therefore, to add a QSpinBox to the tab, in code, you would do the following:

```
QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox(ui->tab);
```

This has set the parent of the spin box to `ui->tab` instead of `this`.

Comment: That was it, I was close! Thank you!